# Making my new carousel have more images across and autoscroll

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm using jquery jcarouselLite and after been baffled at the install, I'm now trying to make the carousel auto-scroll and support 5+ images to be view able at once.

http://goo.gl/58Ds2

I've tried adding the new code from the documentation but this doesn't seem to change anything

$(".auto .jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
    auto: 800,
    speed: 1000
});

Comment: you can view the page source on my website or inspect element to see what I have Romain.

Comment: Well then I can't see any element with the class auto, or the class jCarouselLite

Comment: try now, I tried to add it again but couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: I see it auto-scrolling..

Comment: really on mine its displaying vertically and doesn't work at all

Comment: This is the transition i'm getting (on chrome) http://cl.ly/image/0Z0D3d3o1c3C

Comment: Ohh i mean the carousel at the bottom of the page Romain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div that is supposed to be a slider has a "anyClass" class.

Do the following :

```
$('.anyClass').jCarouselLite({ auto: 800, speed: 1000 });
```

Comment: That bits worked thanks Romain, Now i just need to get it to show more images at once.

Comment: Well your other images are called "someimage", so I guess if you replace this with the actual link to the image, it will work.